# Redirect from page with facebook share tags

Tags: facebook, redirect, video, share

My company sells videohosting services and we offer sharing to facebook of our customer's videos. Videos are hosted on our platform and embedded on a customer's page. When the end user clicks "share" we send a request to facebook to share the video. Facebook requires that the shared page contains meta tags with properties "image_src" and "video_src" (http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162163) and we do this.

The problem from the customer's perspective is that they don't want to modify the  section of their page so we host this share page for them. For example: customer owns website customer.com and embed videos from us so the videos are hosted on provider.com. When the end user clicks share we tell facebook that the correct meta tags for the video can be found on provider.com to make the sharing work. The problem becomes when facebook user's click the link and end up on provider.com instead of customer.com website.

We are thinking about introducing a js redirect from the landing page of provider.com to the appropriate page on customer.com. Technically this would be a good solution for us and for our customer but the question is if this is allowed by facebook?

Comment: I don't think anyone here can really give you a satisfactory answer. Your best bet is to read the terms and conditions and privacy policy thoroughly to see if you can spot anything. If not I'd suggest emailing Facebook support (though not sure how long it will take them to reply). Don't think too many people here can really comment on their policy. https://developers.facebook.com/policy/